# How to style a span which is just after another span with a particular class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and inside 100 spans with class s2 and one span with class s1. This s1 span can be anywhere inside the div. I want to apply css to only the first s2 span which is after the s1. How to do it in css ?

```
<div>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s1"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span> <<- i want to style this span
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    <span class="s2"></span>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <span class="s2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.s1 + .s2 {}` would work in your case.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.s1+.s2 {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

> The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed
>   immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

> This is referred to as an adjacent selector or next-sibling selector. It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

```
.s1 + .s2 { /* CSS here */ }
```

```css
.s1 + .s2 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s1">2</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span> 
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
  <span class="s2">1</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

In CSS, you could do:

```
  .s2:nth-child(5) {}       /* get any .s2 that is the 5th child within its parent */
  .s2:nth-last-child(4) {}  /* get any .s2 that is the 4th from last child within its parent */
  .s1 + .s2 {}              /* get any .s2 that immediately follows an .s1 */
```

In JavaScript, you could do:

```
  document.querySelector(".s2:nth-child(5)").style.....;
  document.querySelector(".s2:nth-last-child(4)").style.....;
  document.querySelector(".s1 + .s2").style.....;
```

These all assume that the hierarchical relationship between all these elements is static.

Learn more about selectors **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)**.

Comment: And you don't even need to use JavaScript; those are all valid selectors in CSS, which is what the OP asked for....

Comment: True, but the question was tagged with "JavaScript", so I offered an answer that would cover both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 operator

.s1 ~ .s2:nth-of-type(1)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

Comment: This also selects _all_ `.s2` elements after `.s1`. The question asked how to select _only_ the next `.s2` element.

Comment: Try adding :nth-of-type(1) after s2